# How I ignore slashes in Ruby Regular Expression

Tags: ruby, regex

```
a = 'CS 141 FALL 2016/SessionData/L1609211319.xml'
Class = a.match(/(.*)SessionData/)
class = Class.to_s 
puts "Class is " + class
```

When I try to match the regular expression of that string it gives me "CS 141 FALL 2016/" When I tried to ignore the '/' after 2016 it didn't work. How do I do it?

Comment: And what did you try "to ignore the '/' after 2016"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried using forward slash but that would be the end of the regular expression. That's why I could not get anywhere.

Comment: Heard of escaping special characters in a regex? A slash is a regex delimiter. Try `a[/(.*)\/SessionData/, 1]`

Comment: You can also run the string through `Regexp.escape`

Comment: This smells like an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)".

Comment: The forward slash is _NOT a special regex character_ that must be escaped. It is just a literal character with no other special meaning. Please don't listen, I'm sick of seeing toothpics leaning.

Comment: The forward slash has to be escaped when the pattern delimiter is also a forward slash. That people don't know alternate characters can be used with the `%r` literal is a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to consider: URLs contain a "path", and that path can easily be extracted using URI, then munged using [File's methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/File.html).

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://example.com/path/to/a/resource.xml')
the_path = uri.path # => "/path/to/a/resource.xml"
File.split(the_path) # => ["/path/to/a", "resource.xml"]
File.basename(the_path) # => "resource.xml"
File.extname(the_path) # => ".xml"
File.basename(the_path, File.extname(the_path)) # => "resource"
File.dirname(the_path) # => "/path/to/a"
File.absolute_path('..', the_path) # => "/path/to/a"
```

There are more methods available, but that gives an idea of what can be done without having to get dirty.

You can also start with String's `split`:

```
the_path.split('/') # => ["", "path", "to", "a", "resource.xml"]
```

then grab the chunks that way too.

Bringing it all home:

```
the_path = 'CS 141 FALL 2016/SessionData/L1609211319.xml'
File.split(the_path) # => ["CS 141 FALL 2016/SessionData", "L1609211319.xml"]
File.basename(the_path) # => "L1609211319.xml"
File.extname(the_path) # => ".xml"
File.basename(the_path, File.extname(the_path)) # => "L1609211319"
File.dirname(the_path) # => "CS 141 FALL 2016/SessionData"

the_path.split('/') # => ["CS 141 FALL 2016", "SessionData", "L1609211319.xml"]
```

and of course:

```
the_path.split('/').first # => "CS 141 FALL 2016"
```

Regular expressions are nice, but often there are effective ways of doing something without resorting to them. If you insist:

```
the_path = 'CS 141 FALL 2016/SessionData/L1609211319.xml'
the_path[ %r#^([^/]+)# ] # => "CS 141 FALL 2016"
```

Ruby's `%r` literal defines whatever is inside the delimiters as a regular expression. The [Regexp documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html) says:

> Regexps are created using the `/.../` and `%r{...}` literals, and by the `Regexp::new` constructor.

Knowing that, it's easy to step around the leaning-toothpick syndrome of dealing with `/.../` as delimiters, forcing the need to escape the delimiters if they're inside the pattern. This'd be the equivalent that only hints at the dragons that wait for the unwary:

```
the_path[ /^([^\/]+)/ ] # => "CS 141 FALL 2016"
```